# Not recognising declaration in FirstViewController even after #import

Tags: iphone, ios5, controller

Does anyone know why a declaration is not recognised in FirstViewController even after importing SecondViewController.h in First?

Here's the code in SecondViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *query;
```

I'm trying to use it in FirstViewController. But it's giving me error -

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            search.text];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                           animated:YES];
    [viewController release];


}
```

"query" is not recognised. Even though the SecondViewController.h is imported in implementation file of FirstViewController.

Comment: You may have imported FirstViewController in SecondViewController so you have to use @class SecondViewController in FirstViewController.

Comment: Please provide more detail, preferably with some source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called circular inclusion. Each header `#import`s the other -- which will be first?

Use forward declarations:

**Before**

```
#import "A.h"
@interface B : NSObject
...
```

**After**

```
@class A; // << forward declaration instead of import
@interface B : NSObject
...
```

---

In more detail: `#import` is just like `#include` with an include-guard.

`#include` is just like copying the included file's contents into the other file (and all files included by it).

If two headers include the other, it's circular inclusion. In C, that's going to result in an error if the two headers depend on the declarations in the other header -- it will encounter an unrecognized identifier.

Now, you can avoid this problem by using a forward declaration: `@class SomeClass;`. This tells the compiler there is an ObjC class named `SomeClass` -- therefore, it does not need to emit a compilation error.

Comment: Elaborate more, please. What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: Tried using the forward declaration, but still it says that 'query' is not declared in FirstViewController.

Comment: Worked, i was doing something wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
// -------------- FirstViewController.h

@class SecondViewController;
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController { 
    SecondViewController *secondViewController;
}
@end

// -------------- FirstViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h" 
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

-(id)init {
    [super init];
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@end
```